# replacing text in jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I have a *Jtextfield* that i need  it to contain only one character as a maximum,so if the user types a character then another one, the other one becomes erased and the new one is typed, it replaces it.Anyone has an idea on how to do that?

Comment: There should be a 'onKey' event of some sort. If you want more help, try showing us what you tried. Google is your friend.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I tried to add a keylistener to the jtextfield but it didn't work, I don't know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DocumentFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html):

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class GUITest
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public void init()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ((JPanel)frame.getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JTextField txt = new JTextField(5);
        ((AbstractDocument) txt.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new OneLetterFilter());

        frame.add(txt);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public void showGUI()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                GUITest gui = new GUITest();
                gui.init();
                gui.showGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class OneLetterFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {
        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
        {
            String oldText = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
            fb.replace(0, oldText.length(), text.substring(text.length() - 1), attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        if(jTextField1.getText().length() >0){
            jTextField1.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Based on what i understood from your problem. This should work

[i Did on NetBeans using jFrameForm]

Comment: No, I think it doesn't solve OP's problem, your are clearing all text if user types more than 1 character, instead it should clear all more than 1 characters.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, where to put this method and how is this method going to me called?

Comment: if you are using netbeans right click on textbox > Events > Key > KeyTyped

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean, but i am not using a jframe form

Comment: @user2249621 Use either: Key-bindings, `DocumentListener` or `DocumentFilter`. In all cases, never use KeyListener.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet How would `Key-bindings` work in this situation?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad In this situation, Key-bindings is not the best option. I was just stating the alternatives of using KeyListener.